# Is it standard to ping on a Websocket?

Tags: javascript, websocket

I have a browser app which creates a Websocket object using javascript. On some laptops the Websocket is being closed if nothing is received by the Websocket after just one minute. What might be the cause and should the backend send a ping now and again? If so, how often should the ping be sent?

Comment: This sounds like a "try it and see" kind of performance/scaling problem. I'm not sure there is a single right answer.

Comment: Ugh, I've heard that some firewalls or routers (etc) might cause problems with sockets because they don't understand them. They just see them as an long running open connection and assume it's just hanging, so they disconnect it.  Presumably outdated network managing software/hardware interfering. Could it be that?